# Does kill() work instantly in C? Or is there a chance the next line runs?

Tags: c, linux

Come to think of it, I guess the signal is sent to the OS and the program will proceed, even if the signal is still pending on the OS side. Can someone confirm?

```
kill(this_process, signum);
printf("will line this run in any reality of the multi-verse?");
printf("or should I go to sleep?");
sleep(10);
```

Comment: The OS is just a machine the handles external events like syscalls and hardware driven interrupts. If you call the kill syscall then the kernel will process it. The nature of signals is that they are asynchronous so there is function that is called upon arrival of a signal. It can happen at anytime. If kill blocked and the process didn't have a handler you would wait forever in your code. By nature it can't block.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted.  It seems like a perfectly clear and reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 4):

From the POSIX specification of [`kill()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/kill.html)

> If the value of *pid* causes *sig* to be generated for the sending process, and if *sig* is not blocked for the calling thread and if no other thread has *sig* unblocked or is waiting in a `sigwait()` function for *sig*, either *sig* or at least one pending unblocked signal shall be delivered to the sending thread before `kill()` returns.

So if there are no other signals pending for the process when you call `kill()`, the signal you send has to be delivered immediately. But if there are other signals pending, this signal could be queued and an earlier signal delivered immediately.

Comment: Trying to understand the case where a different signal gets returned. Can you give me a clear example of when this would be the case?

Comment: Another process sends a signal to this process and the signal is queued. This process calls `kill()`. The first signal might then be delivered when `kill()` returns.